# Django url image extraction like facebook

Tags: django, django-apps

Does anybody know if there is a pluggable app that you can use to achieve url like image extraction for Django?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by 'url like image extraction'.

Comment: when you post an item onto facebook that contains a URL, facebook extracts information from this ie small description image thumbnails etc.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a pluggable app that will do this for you, but you can probably hack this together yourself.

The only 'standard' I know of that facilitates this is oEmbed (http://www.oembed.com/) which basically works this way:

- somebody gives you a URL.
- you read it, find that its a valid JSON that matches the oembed structure
- success!

other than the above, and what I think facebook does as well (since I took a look at a few sites that both twitter and fb would work with and none have any oembed support that I can see), is to work on a case by case basis. They probably had a developer go through a large variety of sites and look at the type of meta tags available. for example, yfrog has a bunch of meta properties that tell you the url directly to the main image being displayed, the owner, the tweet that went along with the image, etc. After that it's best effort guesswork. that's why when you try to share a blog post on facebook, it'll often give you the option of any one of the images that went with that blog post, because it doesn't know which one is the main one.